# How to add a line break after each dynamically created checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's the code for the dynamically created checkboxes. How do I add line breaks to the code so that I have one checkbox per line? I tried to do `document.createElement("br")` and appending it after `get.appendChild(label)` but it didn't work.

```
function setCheckboxes(browser) {
    var get = document.getElementById("get");

    if (browser == "courses") {
        for (var i = 1; i < coursesGetKeys.length; i++) {
            var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
            var label = document.createElement("label");
            checkBox.type = "checkbox";
            checkBox.value = coursesGetKeys[i];
            checkBox.name = "r";
            label.textContent = setOpt(coursesGetKeys[i], browser);
            get.appendChild(checkBox);
            get.appendChild(label);
            //label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(setOpt(validCoursesKeys[i], dataset)));
        }
    }

    if (browser == "rooms") {
        for (var i = 1; i < validRoomsKeys.length; i++) {
            var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
            var label = document.createElement("label");
            checkBox.type = "checkbox";
            checkBox.value = validRoomsKeys[i];
            checkBox.name = "r";
            label.textContent = setOpt(validRoomsKeys[i], browser);
            get.appendChild(checkBox);
            get.appendChild(label);
            //label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(setOpt(validCoursesKeys[i], dataset)));
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already know how to create an input:

```
var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
```

and how to append it:

```
get.appendChild(checkBox); // get is the parent element you selected at the top of your code
```

So your first hunch was correct, you can also do this:

```
var br = document.createElement("br");
get.appendChild(br);
```

which creates a br element, and then also appends it to the "get" parent.

Comment: Where am I supposed to insert the line break? Cause I tried it at the beginning and end of the for loops and it doesn't seem to do what I want.

Comment: At the end of each for-loop. there's two statements that do `appendChild` already. I'd put the two lines right after that. Are there any error messages in your browser's console?

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. It works now. I was only creating one br variable outside the loop then trying to use it over and over it again inside the loop, so it was only applying the line break to the very last element!

Comment: Ah :D That explains it! In that case, you were pointing to one specific br tag - which can only be in one place in your document. So by appending it over and over again, it just ended up in the last place you appended it (but it went missing from the previous places).